# Problems Reopening Apps

Tags: android

I have a strange problem making a chat application.

If I go through the notification, `MessageActivity` appears.

And when I press the back key, call this.

```
 startActivity(new Intent(MessageActivity.this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

The problem is that the `MessageActivity` opens again when I go back to the app after going to the main activity screen with the back key.

With homekey, the MainActivity opens again.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` didn't work.

Comment: call finish() in Message Activity when pressed back button.

Comment: I've already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** in MainActivity when you want go to MessageActivity just startActivity

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
```

and do not finish MainActivity let it be open in background

and when you want get back to MainActivity just finish MessageActivity

```
finish();
```

and do not start any activity because MainActivity already started and is in background.

**2.** or you can do reverse means in MainActivity when you wanna go to MainActivity

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
finish();
```

so the MainActivity finished and is no longer running in background

and in MessageActivity when you wanna go back. start MainActivity and finish current activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(MessageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
finish();
```

## Update:

change flag for notification intent from this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

to this

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: When I open this application with notification, the MainActivity does not open.

Comment: so you just need to finish MessageActivity on back pressed like second way

Comment: I've been doing this for two hours. I've tried everything I can.

Comment: you get this problem when application is already open and you click notification. or when application completely closed

Comment: I realized what I did was stupid. I solved the problem by opening MainActivity first and then opening the next MessageActivity. I'm sorry.